# Append button into 2 class

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to append my button into div with `.class1` and `.class2`

```
<div class="class1"></div>

<div class="class2"></div>
```

I try like this :

```
$(".class1", ".class2").append('<button>My Button</button>');
```

How to do that?

Comment: it should be $(".class1, .class2")

Comment: haha i wanna try something like that, but i think that code 100% will not working.

Comment: it will work surely

Comment: yes sure. hahah

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$(".class1", ".class2")` should go to      `$(".class1, .class2")`

```js
$(".class1, .class2").append('<button>My Button</button>');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="class1"></div>

<div class="class2"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace `$(".class1", ".class2")` to `$(".class1, .class2")`

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code.

```
$('<button>My Button</button>').appendTo('.class1','.class2');
```

Answer (score 0):

it should be

```
$(".class1, .class2").append('<button>My Button</button>');
```

please refer below link for more understanding of multiple selector

https://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/